# ContextErrorException, "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break"

Tags: macos, symfony, symfony-3.3, macos-catalina

I migrate to MacOS Catalina and now I have this Symfony issue on `php bin/console c:c`, but in fact whatever console command.

```
request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? at .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2636) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Warning: \"continue\" targeting switch is equivalent to \"break\". Did you mean to use \"continue 2\"? at .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:2636)"}
```

Any ideas ?

Composer version 1.9.0

Comment: Any ideas? Try googling for the error and then updating your dependencies as the results will suggest.

Comment: not sure why you got downvoted.  I have same issue after migrating to Catalina

Answer (score 0):

I finally downgrade to php 7.1 and reinstall dependencies.